# React-Native RTC view overlap

Tags: android, react-native

I am using video in RTCView and I want to show one small video over another video. But my RTCView is not overlapping with each other. below is my code

```
<RTCView streamURL={this.state.selfViewSrc} style={styles.selfView}/>
{
   mapHash(this.state.remoteList, function(remote, index) {
   return <RTCView key={index} streamURL={remote} style=    {styles.remoteView}/>
  })
}
```

CSS are-

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
selfView: {
    width: width,
    height: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? height-80 : height/2+100,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    zIndex: 0,
},
remoteView: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 2,
    marginTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? -120 : 0,
    width: 120,
    height: 120,
    left: 0,
    borderWidth: .5,
    alignSelf: 'flex-start'
},
```

Comment: Mind posting a screenshot of how it currently looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem issue was with order in which selfview and remoteview are creating, I have to created remote view first to put them over self view.

Thanks everyone!